# Measure theory problem from Folland

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X=Y=[0,1]$, $\mathcal M=\mathcal N=\mathcal B_{[0,1]}$, $\mu=$ Lebesgue measure, and $\nu=$counting measure. If $D={(x,x):x\in [0,1]}$ is the diagonal in $X$x$Y$, then $\int \int \mathcal X_D d\mu d\nu $, $\int \int \mathcal X_D d\nu d\mu $ and $ \int \mathcal X_D d(\mu \times \nu) $ are all unequal.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you know how to integrate over counting measure? Do you know how a product measure is defined? It's difficult to give an answer unless we know what you know.

Comment: Yes, I know how product measure is defined.

Comment: Your third integral should only have one integration symbol.

Comment: You are right. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, well $\int \limits_{[0,1]} \int \limits_{[0,1]} \chi_{D} \, d\nu \,d\mu$ is integration with respect to $nu$, counting measure, first.  For fixed $x$, we are counting how many $y$ satisfy that $(x,y) \in D = \{(x,x) : x \in [0,1] \}$.  But if $x$ is fixed, and ordered pairs in $D$ have both the $x$ and $y$ coordinates equal, then there is only one $y$.  So $\nu(D) = 1$.  Then we are integrating $\int \limits_{[0,1]} 1 \, d\mu = \mu([0,1]) = 1$ since the Lebesgue measure of the unit interval is $1$.

Now, for the other order: $\int \limits_{[0,1]} \int \limits_{[0,1]} \chi_{D} \, d\mu \,d\nu$

First, the inner integral: for fixed $y$, we want to know the Lebesgue measure of the set of $x$ such that $(x,y) \in \{(y,y) : y \in [0,1] \}$.  But $y$ is fixed, and since $x$ must equal $y$, then there is only one $x$, and the Lebesgue measure of a set with a single element is $0$.  Thus, the inner integral evaluates to $0$.  But that means the outer integral is an integral of $0$, so it equals $0$.

This shows that $\int \limits_{[0,1]} \int \limits_{[0,1]} \chi_{D} \, d\nu \,d\mu \neq \int \limits_{[0,1]} \int \limits_{[0,1]} \chi_{D} \, d\mu \,d\nu$.

Then, we know by Fubini's theorem that if our original function $\chi_{D}$ in $X \times Y$ were in $L^{1}(d(\mu \times \nu))$ (i.e., if it had finite integral), then the iterated integrals must be equal.  But we found that the iterated integrals were not equal, so that means the original function is *not* in $L^{1}$, which means its integral is infinite.  That shows that none of the three integrals are equal.

Note that the end of my argument used the fact that the statement $p \to q$ is equivalent to $\neg q \to \neg p$.

Comment: Don't we require the measures to be sigma-finite to apply Fubini's theorem?

Comment: We didn't apply Fubini's theorem.  One version of Fubini's theorem is for $L^{1}$ functions.  Then, if the function is not $L^{1}$, we still have that the integral is iterated if the measures are $\sigma$-finite.  But I didn't need that.  The fact is, *if* $\chi_{D} \in L^{1}$, then by one version of Fubini's theorem, the integral should be iterated and all three integrals should be equal.  That is the $p \implies q$ statement.  So, we showed that two of the integrals are *not* equal (this is $\neg q$).  So it must follow that $\neg p$ holds, i.e., $\chi_{D} \not \in L^{1}$, which means the...

Comment: ...integral is *not* finite, and thus is infinite.

Comment: Basically what I am saying is: One version of Fubini's theorem states if $f \in L^{1}$, then all three integrals are equal ($p \implies q$).  Since we know Fubini's theorem holds for $L^{1}$ fns, we know $p \implies q$ is true.  Then the equivalent statement $\neg q \implies \neg p$ is true.  We showed two of the integrals are *not* equal, i.e., $\neg q$ holds.  So $\neg p$ follows, which means $\int \limits_{X \times Y} \chi_{D} \,d(\mu \times \nu) \not < \infty$.  Since it's not finite, it can't be equal to either of the two integrals we calculated.  So none of the three integrals are equal.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I do not fully understand it. Where we are evaluating $\int \int 1_{D}d\mu(x)dv(y)$, first looking at the inner integral, we fix $y$ because we are evaluating the integral with respect to $x$ correct?

Comment: @MorganWeiss I already replied to your comment a few minutes ago (in case you read the earlier reply), but I deleted the reply because I think it might be confusing.  Let me re-reply in a new comment and hopefully clarify.

Comment: @MorganWeiss The iterated integral $\int \int \Bbb 1_{D}(x,y) \,d\mu(x)\,d\nu(y)$ can be thought of as first integrating the map $$x \mapsto \Bbb 1_{D}(x,y)$$ with respect to $\mu$ (where different values of $y$ give different maps) since the inner integral is with respect to $x$.  So, for each $y$ we get a different map that we are integrating.  But we want to do the integration with $y$ still a variable so that we get a formula of the variable $y$ where we can just plug values of $y$ into it and get the integrals of the different maps (of different values of $y$).

Comment: @MorganWeiss Then, if we say $f(y) := \int \Bbb 1_{D}(x,y) \,d\mu(x)$, then this map $$y \to f(y)$$ will be integrated with respect to $\nu$, i.e., the outer integral.

Comment: @user46944 That is really confusing, can you simplify that. I do not understand how we are integrating with respect to y still in the first integral

Comment: @MorganWeiss We **aren't** integrating with respect to $y$ in the inner integral.  But none-the-less $y$ is present in it.  That's all I was trying to say: $y$ is present in the inner integral, but it acts like a constant.  Is that clear?

Comment: Yes, so when you say for fixed $y$ your are basically saying I am treating $y$ as a constant?

Comment: @MorganWeiss That's exactly right.  If I say "for fixed $y$", it's just another way to say we are treating $y$ as a constant.

Comment: Ok, I seem to have troubles with product measures do you have any reference material so that I can confidently solve these types of problems?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32169/discussion-between-user46944-and-morgan-weiss).

Comment: this only works couse the argument holds for every fixed  x or y not just for any x and y . Just in case anybody else has a similar confusion as me.